# Testing e2e in Angular, best practice

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Probably there are already around some answers to this question but I haven't find the one I was looking for my specific scenario. So, here is my situation: I'm working on a web app made in Angular where all the unit tests are using mock data. Then we have some end to end tests written in Protractor. I'm not very excited about them because we are testing the user interface with the data we get from a live api. I think we're using this approach because we have no control on the back-end but the side effect of this is that the database could change a mess up our tests. Also, the api we're using for the e2e is runnung on an internal network meaning that we cannot run tests outside of the office. I was thinking about mocking the http responses in order to mock the database and being able to run all the tests from anywhere. The problem is that the backend logic could act differently from the one we simulate in our tests meaning that as soon as we deploy the application, it will work in an unexpected way.

What is the best practice and workflow to follow in a similar situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice is subjective but there are known solutions each with pros/cons.

**Using a shared environment**
If you have manual testing on the same environment as your automated tests you will risk someone screwing with your tests. Copying data from production to this environment will also halt your tests and is not good. There is extra effort in making your test idempotent by ensuring the setup is in the correct state that your test expects as well as ensuring the data set up is not conflicting with manual tests. It is recommended when you create an entity during test setup to have it created with some unique token related to the test so that it is unique for that test. This is just hard and costly.

**Using separate e2e environment**
This is clearly easier on your test idempotence as you have more control of the data and no manual intervention. You can empty the database or reseed it using several solutions (see below) before every test or group of tests. Still you must be careful ensuring tests do not depend on each other or interfere with other tests.

**Mock the APIs**
You can mock APIs however it is not a true e2e test. Consumer-driven contracts will work if you know that the APIs are testing against specific output and you can then use those outputs as mocks for your inputs of the e2e. These tests are blazing fast. If you don't have control over your environment and its data, or it is a 3rd party system it is recommended to mock the api. You risk not testing the real integration which can cause a lot of failures.

**Use APIs to set up test data**
This is a pretty good solution as not only does it catch issues with APIs but it keeps your e2e tests focused only on the area being tested and you do not have to set up data using the GUI. Test setup and clean up can be managed this way. It may be quicker than using the GUI to set up and certainly not quicker than mocking the API responses.

**Use the GUI to set up the test data**
This can work but you must be smart about it. Since you are sharing the environment with manual testing you must ensure the data is in the correct state. It is wise to create separate entities related to your tests and not share any test cases that someone would touch manually testing around. This is slower. This complicates your tests as you spend a majority of your time navigating around and setting up things in the GUI.

**Use scripts to load the data directly to the database**
Avoid this because there is probably business logic that you are missing and will lead to incorrect states. It is better to go through the API to load data as it can validate the input and run any business logic.

Here are some relevant resources to follow up on:

- [Martin Fowler's write-up on testing microservices](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/)
- https://medium.com/how-we-build-fedora/e2e-testing-with-angular-protractor-and-rails-725fbefb8149#.9rziv2gtp

Answer (score 1):

How about getting a test version of the backend deployed that has a limited amout of data in?

That way, after each round of testing has completed the database can then be reset with the original datasets loaded in.

This would ensure consistency in your result across tests, and means if the backend guys make changes to their master branch, it wont affect your tests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is already, more or less, what we're doing. We use a QA backend with is running only from our internal network and should be up to date with the latest API version. However running tests simultaneously with other users will cause some conflicts. Also, the database we use in that environment is not the one we have in production and we make assertions in the tests where we expect to have some specific informations returned just because we populated the test database in that way.

Comment: So you are testing on a version that is also used by other users? Are these users doing manual testing? Or are these users doing demo's, etc?

Comment: yes @mindparse, we are testing using a shared backend used sometimes for both developing, testing and demo as well

Comment: Ok, well that's always going to cause you problems for repeatable tests. We are in the exact same situation, working alongside a backend team in the same office, and are currently setting up protractor tests to be kicked off from our build server (we are using Jenkins). Right now, we are also using a shared backend same reasons as you, but are hitting the same problems, so are exploring getting a test only backend setup - not yet done though!

Comment: Ok but in our case we can decide and redesign the way we run tests. I was just looking for a best practice answer so that we can have a guideline to follow